# Get column block count using PHP method render_block

Tags: php, block-editor

```php
function get_column_count($block_content, $block){
  if('core/columns' === $block['blockName']){
    // get columns count
    $columnsCount = count(array_column($block['innerBlocks'], 'blockName')); // works, return number of columns
    // do stuff
  }

  if('core/column' === $block['blockName']){
    // get column count
    $columnCount = count($block['blockName']; // doesn't work 
    // do stuff
  }
}

add_filter('render_block', 'get_column_count', 10, 2);
```

Trying to get `column` blocks count here but code above doesn't work. Any input appreciated.

Comment: what are you doing that needs this? There are other ways to solve these kinds fo problems that don't involve this but without knowing why you want to do this it's not possible to advise on the appropriate solution, or even how to do what you asked. There's also a syntax error in your code, can you include the actual code you're using? Avoid making the question too generic/abstract, and incude real concrete examples

Comment: e.g. if you're trying to style them differently then there are pure CSS solutions such as `.wp-block-columns > .wp-block-column:nth-child(2)` would style only the second column, or a block style on the `core/column` block that would let you apply a style in the block editor to an individual column. There are even CSS based solutions that count the number of child elements that can be used: https://crinkles.dev/writing/use-the-child-element-count-in-css/, doing this in PHP however would not be done via the `render_block` filter, but without knowing why you want this I can't say how to do it